# undefined method error for Hash when using select_tag with options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following array:

```
[{:gig_id=>"1234BN-92846",
  :albums_sold=>
   [{:id=>"all-music", :name=>"All Music"},
    {:id=>"presto", :name=>"Presto"},
    {:id=>"hello", :name=>"Hello"}],
  :clothing_sold=>
   [{:id=>"all-clothing", :name=>"All Clothing"},
    {:id=>"cool-shirt", :name=>"Cool Shirt"},
    {:id=>"manchester-united-hoodie", :name=>"Manchester United Hoodie"},
    {:id=>"manchester-united-tank-top", :name=>"Manchester United Tank-Top"},
    {:id=>"manchester-united-hat", :name=>"Manchester United Hat"},
    {:id=>"manchester-united-shirt", :name=>"Manchester United Shirt"}],
  :promos_sold=>
   [{:id=>"all-promo", :name=>"All Promo"},
    {:id=>"jb-bobblehead", :name=>"JB Bobblehead"},
    {:id=>"poster", :name=>"Poster"}]},
 {:gig_id=>"1234BN-78234",
  :clothing_sold=>
   [{:id=>"all-clothing", :name=>"All Clothing"}, {:id=>"cool-shirt", :name=>"Cool Shirt"}]}]
```

I have a select_tag defined as:

```
<%= select_tag "All Music, options_from_collection_for_select(name_object[:albums_sold], :id, :name) %>
```

where name_object is an environment variable that is defined as:

```
<% name_object = @band.all_merch_items_names.find { |key| key[:gig_id] == gig } %>
```

Band#all_merch_items_names generates the array at the top.

I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `name' for {"id"=>"all-music", "name"=>"All Music"}:Hash
```

I have tried changing the keys to symbols ('id', 'name') and change them in options_from_collection_for_select as well to 'id' and 'name' but I keep getting the same error.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a dropdown list with id's attached to each element so that I can hide/show div's with the same id's on select. If there's a better way to implement the select_tag, please do suggest.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the problem using options_for_select:

```
<%= select_tag "All Music, options_for_select(name_object[:albums_sold].collect {|item| [item[:name], item[:id]]}) %>
```